# Wireless (240-300') monitor/keyboard/mouse extender

Tags: monitors, wireless, keyboards, mice

We have a situation where we want to extend a second display (hdmi to large screen TV), Keyboard, and Mouse approximately 240-300 feet away from the computer.

This is a situation where we can't really do remote control into the pc, or we'd do that, but it would be extremely beneficial to duplicate the display at the computer, with one down range about 250 feet away. In addition to that, it would be great if a person a that remote location could move the focus and type in 7 digit numbers from that remote display.

I've been investigating and haven't found anything yet, but it seemed like someone would have come up with port extender or something that would work on a wifi network to accomplish things like this.

Anyone know of anything that might work?

Kip

Comment: Why does remote desktop or VNC not work for you in this situation? WiFi can't be repurposed in the way you asked for, anything transmitted over a "WiFi" connection would have to work within the rules of WiFi & networks. So a means of transmiting video and user input over "WiFi" is essentially what remote desktop is. Other wireless video solutions may exist that can go 300ft, but I have never heard of a device that can support 2-way USB connections over a 300ft distance wirelessly. You have more options if you would consider using cat5/6 cables since both HDMI & USB can be passed through them.

Comment: The issue is the type of machine. This is a kiosk type system with a generic login and that login is extremely restricted on the network. As far as RDC solutions, company policy prevents it. Corporate rules. We don't have to like em, just obey them.

Comment: Then that means your options are either a *very* specialized device or using cat 5/6 cables to go *most* of the distance. I only know how to help with finding products for the latter.